# Connect AWS API Gateway with Fargate Service without load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-fargate

Is it possible to connect API Gateway with Fargate Service directly (whitout using a load balancer). I'm working in a development environment and I don't want to waste money in the load balancer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is still relevant but I was also searching for a solution where API Gateway could be connected to ECS Containers without the need for a (expensive) Load Balancer. Thought of an AWS Lambda Proxy first but there seems to be a more elegant and direct solution which makes the need to write and maintain AWS Lambda Code obsolete.

Basically you will need an API Gateway HTTP Private Integrations API, a VPC Link to create trust between your Gateway and ECS resources and Cloud Map to enable Service Discovery. Here some resources that go a little more into the details on how to it:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-private.html
- https://awsteele.com/blog/2022/10/15/cheap-serverless-containers-using-api-gateway.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a DNS entry that can address all the containers you're running, you would need a load balancer.